# Vba beginner question: same macro applied differently shows different behaviour

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following question:
The code you see below has been pasted in an excel object

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DAY, other As Range
Set DAY = Range("b4:af4")

If Not Intersect(DAY, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
ActiveCell.Copy
Sheets("SP Analysis").Activate
Range("b2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'ElseIf Not Intersect(other, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

End If
End Sub
```

The macro runs but it doesn't copy the activecell in the sheet SP Analysis.

If I change the code with the following:

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) Application.ScreenUpdating = False Dim DAY, other As Range Set DAY = Range("b4:af4")

If Not Intersect(DAY, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then Call TEST

'ElseIf Not Intersect(other, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then End If End Sub
```

with macro TEST doing

```
sub test
  ActiveCell.Copy
Sheets("SP Analysis").Activate
Range("b2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
end sub
```

The command does what is supposed to do.
Question is why? what's the difference between one method and the other?
And, how can I have the command working in an excel object rather than having to call a macro?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use `Target` rather than `ActiveCell` although in this case I don't know why the latter wouldn't work. And we can transfer the value directly without having to activate anything.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim DAY As Range, other As Range   'need to specify type for each variable, otherwise Variant
Set DAY = Range("b4:af4")

If Not Intersect(DAY, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel=True
    Sheets("SP Analysis").Range("b2").Value = Target.Value  'use target
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True   'turn it back on

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello SJR, thanks for the quick answer, your code works, question is:
Why have you added this command: Cancel=True
What it does?
Thanks

Comment: This prevents the default behaviour. Normally when you double-click on a cell it goes into edit mode, the cursor appears. We don't want this (presumably). If in fact you are double clicking on a cell and changing the contents and then pressing enter this would explain why your code didn't work as the active cell would then have been a different cell than Target.